# use lodash for iterating the array and filter

Tags: javascript, reactjs, lodash

I have a function called as

```
getFileterMenus = (menus, filterMenu) => {
    let filteredMenus = _.filter(menus, menu => menu.title !== filterMenu)
    return filteredMenus
  }
```

Here `filterMenu` I want to pass it as an array . which will be like ['first', 'second'] like this. I want to keep a filter function as well..
I tried

```
getFileterMenus = (menus, filterMenu) => {
         let filteredMenus = []
         for (let i = 0; i <= filterMenu.length - 1; i++) {
           filteredMenus = _.filter(menus, menu => menu.title !== filterMenu[i])
          } 
        return filteredMenus
      }
```

Is there any other way to do this than using a loop ?

Comment: yes , there can be more than one so adding as an array

Comment: I assume that `filterMenu` is a **whitelist of items you want to keep** from the `menus` array?

Comment: From Code, menus is something which has all elements and filtermenu is something which I need to remove from menus

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that `menus` is an array of objects and `filterMenu` contains an array of titles that you want to filter for, you can do it with ES6 completely [without using lodash](https://youmightnotneed.com/lodash/), using a combination of [`Array.prototype.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [`Array.prototype.includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes):

```
getFileterMenus = (menus, filterMenu) => {
  return menus.filter(menu => !filterMenu.includes(menu.title));
}
```

If you really want to get creative at the expense of readability, a one-liner with object destructring:

```
getFileterMenus = (menus, filterMenu) => menus.filter(({ title })=> !filterMenu.includes(title))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `includes()` function ([here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_includes_array.asp))

```
getFileterMenus = (menus, filterMenu) => {
    let filteredMenus = _.filter(menus, menu => !filterMenu.includes(menu.title))
    return filteredMenus
  }
```

Comment: In fact, you don't even need `_.filter`, using `menus.filter(menu => <predicate>)` will work just as fine :)

Comment: @Terry can you please add it as an answer... that would be really helpful

Comment: It depends if menus is an object or an array. Because if it is an object `menus.filter(menu => <predicate>)` would not work ^^

Answer (score 0):

To take two arrays with items that have a different format (object and string in your case), you can use lodash's [`_. differenceWith()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#differenceWith).

```
getFileterMenus = (menus, filterMenu) =>
  _.differenceWith(
    menus, 
    filterMenu, 
    (menu, title) => menu.title === title
  )
```